# Convert float to range using Visual Studio snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, textmate, vscode-extensions

I have multiple integers/float for which I have to write it's range very frequently.

for ex.

- from `23134928342` to `[10000000000-99999999999]` (the length should be preserverd)
- from `123.456` to `100.000-999` (start of range should represent exact number of decimal as the given number)

As I have to write too many ranges into the document, I want to make a snippet into the Visual Studio Code. (Also want to learn snippet creation in it)

How to convert the float `123.456` to `000.000-999` using snippet?

**What I tried so far:**

1. to convert digit directly:

   ```
   "Int Replace" : {
       "prefix" : "learn",
       "body": [
           "${CLIPBOARD/(\\d)/0/g}-${CLIPBOARD/(\\d)/9/g}"
               ],
       "description": "Eventgenstart"
   }
   ```

   output : from `123` to `000-999`, from `123.123` to `000.000-999.999`

Though I am not able to figure out how to convert `123.123` to `100.000-999` or atleast to `000.000-999`

Any suggestion would be great help.! 
Note : This task can be done by a python script. but it is not possible in my document as I have to copy only selected numbers whose selection (I don't think) can not be done by a neural network (at the moment).